# Data Calibration

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, spectral-python

I am trying to do Data calibration of Hyperspectral Image of size e.g.,(400,400,150)i.e.,(rows. columns, bands) with standard references... dark image of size(100,400,150) and white Image of size (200,400,150) using the formula,
**Calibrated_Data = (Image_data - dark Image) / (white Image - dark Image)**

I am using the python, have tried to do using numpy but got an error,
"**operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (400,400,150) (100,400,150)**"

Also there is an another way to do it but not sure how can I do it in coding with different size matrices,
**Calibrated_data(x, y, wavelengths) = data(x, y, wavelengths) - dark(x, wavelengths) / white(x, wavelengths) - dark(x, wavelengths)**
Looking for some insights to solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: The first equation is not possible for images/matrices of different sizes. Not only in numpy but also mathematically. Is it possible that your images are of size (400,150) ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to do that but the data_image is (400,400,150) and dark_image, white image of sizes (400,150)

Comment: what are your spatial dimensions and what are your spectral dimensions? I suspect that in your hyperspectral image your spatial dimensions are (400,150). But I could be wrong.

Comment: Hii again, spatial dimensions are (400-lines, 400-samples) and spectral dimension is 150-bands

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot help you further as I do not know enough about this. I initially thought you had 2D images as in x-coordinates and y-coordinates and wavelengths. But I do not know how to calculate using lines and samples.

Comment: For giving you some more information I have added those lines and samples because we scan and collect the data in that format. But you are right actually I have( x- coordinates, y-coordinates, wavelengths) What if I have same format as you mentioned, Is it possible to do calibration for that?

Comment: If you have x-coordinates and y-coordinates then you could use your first equation. Although then the white and dark image should have the same spacial and spectral conditions (same dimensions). source: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00837756/document

Comment: Thank you @joostblack, it was helpful to some extent!